# Яндекс неправильное выполнения программы!

Tags: golang

помогите найти проблему!!!
Условия задачи
Задача для тех кто хорошо справляется с курсом.

После урока про сортировки Маша решила применить полученные знания с пользой.

У неё есть тетрадка, куда она записывает всех, кому за что-нибудь благодарна. Список может быть очень длинным, но Маша его упорядочила по алфавиту (это называется - лексикографический порядок).

Помогите ей организовать быстрый поиск по этому списку.

Формат ввода
На первой строке передается количество людей в списке - натуральное число. Затем на следующих строках идет список людей. А после списка - перечень префиксов всех тех, кого надо найти. Перечень префиксов может быть произвольной длины. Пустая строка вместо префикса значит что префиксы закончились.

Формат вывода
Для каждого префикса необходимо вывести первую фамилию с таким префиксом, или фразу Не найдено.

Мой код

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func findPeopleWithPrefixes(people []string, prefixes []string) []string {
    foundPeople := []string{}
    for _, person := range people {
        for _, prefix := range prefixes {
            if prefix == "" || strings.Contains(person, prefix) {
                foundPeople = append(foundPeople, person)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return foundPeople
}

func main() {
    var numPeople int
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&numPeople)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Ошибка ввода количества людей:", err)
        return
    }

    peopleList := []string{}
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for i := 0; i < numPeople; i++ {
        person, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        peopleList = append(peopleList, strings.TrimSpace(person))
    }

    prefixes := []string{}
    for {
        prefix, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        prefix = strings.TrimSpace(prefix)
        if prefix == "" {
            break
        }
        prefixes = append(prefixes, prefix)
    }

    foundPeople := findPeopleWithPrefixes(peopleList, prefixes)

    for i := len(foundPeople); i < numPeople; i++ {
        foundPeople = append(foundPeople, "не найдено")
    }
    for _, person := range foundPeople {
        fmt.Println(person)
    }
}
```

Вот что выводит в IDE Goland
[image: Вот что выводит в IDE Goland]

Вот что выдает мне проверка от яндекса
[image: Вот что выдает мне проверка от яндекса]

У меня вопрос ошибка в проверке яндекса или же в моем коде
Если в моем коде то прошу указать причину(

Comment: У меня ваш код выдаёт такой же результат, что и у проверочной системы Яндекса. Проверьте, что вы загрузили в систему именно ту версию кода, которую вы запускаете в Goland.

Comment: Приветствую! Спасибо за ответ) но я только что скопировал код с данной страницы и в IDE у меня все прекрасно) Подскажите вы вводите
3
Иванов Иван   
Петренко Тарас
Петров Дмитрий
Ив
Петр
Петра

Какой у вас выввод?

Comment: Да, ввёл эти данные. Вывод: Иванов Иван
Петренко Тарас
Петров Дмитрий

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста) Почему тогда у меня может быть такой вывод? Если можно можем списать в Тг или же в Дс

Comment: не сможешь помочь, у меня в vsc выдает все верно,а в яндекс lmn выдает везде "Не найдено"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `findPeopleWithPrefixes` замените внешний и внутренний цикл местами. То есть итерироваться надо не сначала по людям, а потом по префиксам, а наоборот:

```
func findPeopleWithPrefixes(people []string, prefixes []string) []string {
    foundPeople := []string{}
    for _, prefix := range prefixes {        // Внешний цикл по префиксам
        for _, person := range people {      // Внутренний цикл по людям
        
            if prefix == "" || strings.Contains(person, prefix) {
                foundPeople = append(foundPeople, person)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return foundPeople
}
```

А ваш код вместо того, чтобы искать одно подходящее совпадение для каждого префикса, ищет каждого человека, для которого есть хотя бы один подходящий префикс. Естественно, он вам находит и Петренко, и Петрова, т.к. среди префиксов есть тот, который подходит им обоим.

UPD: Кстати, есть подозрение, что ваш код будет неправильно работать для тех случаев, когда ненайденные префиксы идут не в конце списка, а в середине.

Comment: Спасибо огромное) но теперь у меня другая ошибка)) Different number of lines: out = 100, corr = 2

Comment: На тех же тестовых данных или уже на другой проверке?

Comment: Другой тест) Первый тест прошел! благодарю) теперь на тесте 2 выдает ошибку Different number of lines: out = 100, corr = 2

Comment: Мне надо видеть, что там за данные. Отметьте этот ответ как решение, и следующий тестовый кейс оформите новым вопросом, я посмотрю.

Comment: Вот так?) я не особо разбираюсь)

Comment: Проблема решена! Спасибо огромное всем за помощь